# How to write Rspec testing for RestFul api in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest, rspec, bdd

I have created few Api's for my rails project. Now i would like to write some testing code for it.

I have heard about Rspec and also found few articles which deals with Rest Api's. but in all that article i haven't found any specification deals with external parameters.

So is there any possible solution were i can pass parameters from terminal along with Rspec command or any other standard way.

I am totally new to BDD or any other TDD so please correct me if my intention gone wrong.

Comment: _but in all that article i haven't found any specification deals with external parameters._ What do you mean?

Comment: https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/request-specs/request-spec

The `type: :request` gives you access to methods like `get` and ability to pass header and body params.

Comment: You don't pass params from the terminal. You create scenarios which can be run deterministically and that give the same result regardless of how you run the spec suite.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to pass any external parameters along with `rspec`. All needed parameters are put in spec file. So if your `REST API` endpoint accepts parameter `include_tweets`, in a test file it will be just

```
it 'shows resource with tweets' do
  get :show, include_tweets: true
end
```

If you want to test with different arguments, you create a separate test.

```
it 'shows resource with tweets' do
  get :show, include_tweets: false
end
```

I hope I understood correctly what you're asking